# Query Names (First Name and Last Name)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm working on a MySQL Query in Node.js to search a table of staff members, in which the columns are split up into firstname and lastname

Table Structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9673e

Here's the two queries i've tried

```
var FullName = req.query.FullName
const TEST2 = "SELECT StaffList.FirstName, StaffList.LastName, CONCAT(StaffList.FirstName, ' ' ,StaffList.LastName) AS FullName FROM StaffList WHERE CONCAT(StaffList.FirstName, ' ' ,StaffList.LastName) LIKE ? "
const TEST5 = "SELECT StaffList.FirstName, StaffList.LastName, CONCAT_WS(' ',StaffList.FirstName,StaffList.LastName) AS FullName FROM StaffList WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',StaffList.FirstName,StaffList.LastName) LIKE ? "
connection.query(TEST5,FullName,(error,results) => {
    if (error){
        return res.send(error)
    }
    else{
        return res.json({
            data: results
        })
    }
})
```

But it only returns a name from my DB if I put in exactly the right first AND last name

So i tried separating it

```
const TEST6 = "SELECT StaffList.FirstName, StaffList.LastName FROM StaffList WHERE FirstName LIKE ? or LastName LIKE ? "
connection.query(TEST6,[FirstName,LastName],(error,results) => {
    if (error){
        return res.send(error)
    }
    else{
        return res.json({
            data: results
        })
    }
})
```

And it returns the right value if just ONE of the fields are correct

How do I get it so that it returns values that are similair?

Eg) 
Tom Smith
Smith Robertson
Searching 'Smith' to return both these people regardless if the search value refers to firstname or lastname

Comment: well if you search "Smith" then your last query (TEST6) should return what you want. You may want to consider helping by using wildcards, if you aren't already - Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd0c71/2

Comment: Is that possible to do with TEST6? In my mind it wouldn't becuase in the URL it's broken up like:

endpoint?FirstName=&LastName=

Comment: oh I see so you have two totally separate input values? I think that might be a logical mistake. Just let the user search for "name" as a single field and let the backend handle looking in each of the DB fields - by looking for the same value in each, or by concatenating them and then looking for the "name" input within the concatenated value (more like your TEST2 or TEST5 examples). The user doesn't need to care how you store the data. If they're just interested in finding a person they won't be interested in the distinction between first and last names.

Comment: e.g. We have a standard autocomplete plugin where I work which we put into web apps to allow people to do a search for staff members - the user just types whatever they like and it goes away and looks in the database for staff where (any part of) the concatenated first and last names match the string, OR their (any part of) their username matches the string. Works quite nicely like that, much easier than separate input fields.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your help - got it working for FullName. Will look into autocomplete also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want not only the exact name but also partial
you could use wildchar

```
 "SELECT StaffList.FirstName, StaffList.LastName 
    FROM StaffList 
    WHERE FirstName LIKE concat('%', ? ,'%') 
    OR LastName LIKE concat('%', ? '%') ";
```